# ¿como puedo tener un componente dialog compartido en Angular?

Tags: angular, modulos, reactiveformsmodule

estoy tratando de crear un componente que tenga un dialog y poderlo reusar en varios modulos. El componente tendrá un formulario con reactiveForms dentro del dialog. Tengo un modulo shared con la siguiente forma:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule , FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { PaginatorComponent } from './paginator/paginator.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '@material/material.module';
import { ScrollToModule } from '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to';
import { LogDialogComponent } from '@auth/log-dialog/log-dialog.component';
// import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavBarComponent, PaginatorComponent, FooterComponent, LogDialogComponent],
  providers: [ NavBarComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ScrollToModule.forRoot()
    // SwiperModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavBarComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    PaginatorComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LogDialogComponent
    // SwiperModule
    // MaterialModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

el componente que quiero poder usar en varios modulos es `LogDialogComponent` , este es el .ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '@auth/services/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SnackbarService } from '@core/services/snackbar.service';
import { rutValidator } from '../../../shared/formValidators/rut.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log-dialog',
  templateUrl: './log-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-dialog.component.css']
})
export class LogDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  step: number;
  typeUser: string = '';
  deliveryEnterpriseId: string = '';
  showMessage: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private snackBar: SnackbarService
  ){}

  enterpriseForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group(
    {
      nameEnterprise: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]],
      run: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
      address: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4) ]],
      phone: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\+?56)?(\s?)(0?9)(\s?)[9876543]\d{7}$/) ]],
      communeEnterprise: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
      provinceEnterprise: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
      regionEnterprise: ['', [ Validators.required ]]
    },
    {
      validators: rutValidator
    }
  );

.
.
.
.
```

El error que estoy recibiendo ahora es este:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.` .

Entiendo que este error sucede cuándo no se ha importado ReactiveFormsModule , pero si se fijan, lo tengo importado en el `SharedModule`.

Me haría falta importar algo mas en algún otro módulo? ttal vez en el modulo donde estoy llamando al componente `LogDialogComponent` ? esto de las importaciones a veces me cuesta un poco y tengo ya tiempo intentando solucionar este error y no he podido.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayuda.

Comment: `SharedModule` tiene que importar `ReactiveFormsModule` para que `LogDialogComponent` pueda usarlo.

Comment: @Lobos amigo, los tengo importados arriba, en el sharedModule tengo importado tanto el formsModule como el ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: Lo siento, me refiero dentro del arreglo `imports`

Comment: Probaré... otra duda que básicamente es la misma, yo cree un modulo que se llama ```material``` , ahí importo solo los modulos de angular material que voy a usar en mi proyecto, y posteriormente lo importo en los modulos donde voy a hacer uso de de uno de esos modulos de angular material, pero también me da error, así que termino importando directamente desde @angular/material y no desde dle modulo que creeé. com osería la forma correcta?

Comment: El `NgModule` tiene dos arreglos `imports` y `exports`. Para el caso de tu módulo `material` ,que solo sirve para agrupar los componentes de material ,los módulos deben ir en el arreglo `exports` y con eso ya estaría listo para reusarlo en otros módulos.

Comment: Solo en el Export? en mi caso los importo ariba (fuera del @ngmodule, luego los tengo en el arreglo de imports y por en el arreglo de exports.